# How do to count the number of elements in a list?

Tags: lisp

So here is my code. It should count the number of elements in a list but instead it prints a zero even though a list contains something.

```
(defun my-list (listA)
    (setq count 0)
    (loop for i in listA
    if(null i)
        count
    else
    do (setq count(+ count 1))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have tagged functional programming, but the solution you are trying to do is far from functional.

A functional approach would be to have a case analysis. The base case would be a empty list. The answer would be 0. The default case would be the length of the `rest` of the list plus one. eg. `(my-length '(1)) ==> (1+ (my-length '()) ==> (1+ 0) ==> 1`

That's it. It works for any length list since `(my-length '(1 2 3)) ==> (1+ (1+ (1+ 0))) ==> 3`

**EDIT**

Where is `count` defined? `setq` updates an existing binding. Perhaps you should use `let` to make a local binding. Also in `loop` you can make variables:

```lisp
(loop :for count :from 0 
      :for element :in listA
      :finally (return count))
```

`loop` actually can count, sum and a whole lot more so this is a better way:

```lisp
(loop :for element :in listA
      :counting t)
```

Comment: i tagged the functional accidentally. my bad.